# Example of non-degenerate random variable with odd moments = 0

Tags: probability, expected-value, variance

Think of one example of a random variable which is non-degenerate for which all the odd moments are identically zero. Give the probability mass function of the random variable and state a quantity it could represent.

At first I thought of rolling a die since it's non-degenerate, but I don't believe its odd moments are 0. Is anyone able to come up with an example and briefly explain it?

Comment: As tommik's answer shows, any $X$ symmetric about $0$ for which all moments exist will work.  Is there an example not symmetric about $0$?

Comment: I posted my question separately here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3919440/442

Answer (score 3):

**1. Continuous Random Variable**

A standard gaussian, $X\sim N(0;1)$ works.

$$\mathbb{E}[X^{2n+1}]=0$$

$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

The proof is quite easy expanding its MGF in Taylor series and derivating

It can represent the measurement error when measuring the length of the following stick

[image]

**2. Discrete Random Variable**

$Y$ is a random variable taking the values $Y=\pm1$ with probability $\mathbb{P}[Y=-1]=\mathbb{P}[Y=1]=\frac{1}{2}$

$$\mathbb{E}[Y^{2n+1}]=\frac{1}{2}[(-1)^{2n+1}+1^{2n+1}]=0$$

$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

$Y$ represents the following function

$$Y=2X-1$$

Where $X\sim B\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)$, a Bernoulli rv with parameter 0.5

It can represent the random gain when playing "toss a fair coin game"  winning $\$1$ if H and loosing $\$1$  if T